# Getting OpenID to work on an existing MyBB Install

Tags: php, sql, openid, mybb

I am the administrator for a forum,[The Vortex](http://eyeofthevortexonline.com/mybb/).  It operates on the latest version of MyBB ver1.6.3. I would like to know how I can get OpenID to become the login for the forums, and also add the users to the MyBB Sql file and overwrite any users that are already registered.  This must work on an existing install as I will not be dumping my SQL database to do a fresh install just to get OpenId to work.  Any Thought?

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for MyBB that does what you need. Check it out here:

http://mods.mybb.com/view/openid